# ASP.NET Shopping Cart

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, shopping-cart

I am in the middle of building a very simple shopping cart in asp.net with a VB backend but I am running into problems with my code. When I run my application and try to add a product to the cart I get an error message.

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error:

```
Line 27:         Dim blnMatch As Boolean = False
Line 28: 
Line 29:         For Each Me.objDR In objDT.Rows
Line 30:             If objDR("StockItemName") = Product Then
Line 31:                 objDR("Quantity") += txtQuantity.Text
```

I am not sure why it is doing this and was hoping that perhaps someone could take a look and offer up some advice? I have checked over my code and I cannot find anything wrong however I would take any guidence that you may have on it.

Here is my code.

**Shoppingcart.aspx**

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddlProducts" runat="server">
```

Socks
Pants
Shirt
Hat

Quantity:








Total:

**Shoppingcart.aspx.vb**
Imports System.Data
Partial Public Class Shoppingcart
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

```
Dim objDT As System.Data.DataTable
Dim objDR As System.Data.DataRow
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        makeCart()
    End If
End Sub
'Mark Cart function
Function makeCart()
    objDT = CType(Session("Cart"), DataTable)
    objDT.Columns.Add("StockID", GetType(Integer))
    objDT.Columns("StockID").AutoIncrement = True
    objDT.Columns("StockID").AutoIncrementSeed = 1

    objDT.Columns.Add("StockItemName", GetType(String))
    objDT.Columns.Add("StockItemValue", GetType(Decimal))
    Session("Cart") = objDT
End Function
'This is for adding items to the shopping cart.
Sub AddToCart(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    objDT = Session("Cart")
    Dim Product As String = ddlProducts.SelectedItem.Text
    Dim blnMatch As Boolean = False

    For Each Me.objDR In objDT.Rows
        If objDR("StockItemName") = Product Then
            objDR("Quantity") += txtQuantity.Text
            blnMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If Not blnMatch Then
        objDR = objDT.NewRow
        objDR("Quantity") = txtQuantity.Text
        objDR("StockItemName") = ddlProducts.SelectedItem.Text
        objDR("StockItemValue") = Decimal.Parse(ddlProducts.SelectedItem.Value)
        objDT.Rows.Add(objDR)
        Session("Cart") = objDT
    End If

    dg.DataSource = objDT
    dg.DataBind()
End Sub
Function GetItemTotal() As Decimal
    Dim intCounter As Integer
    Dim decRunningTotal As Decimal

    For intCounter = 0 To objDT.Rows.Count - 1
        objDR = objDT.Rows(intCounter)
        decRunningTotal += (objDR("StockItemValue") * objDR("Quantity"))
    Next

    Return decRunningTotal
End Function
Sub Delete_Item(ByVal s As Object, ByVal e As DataGridCommandEventArgs)

    objDT = Session("Cart")
    objDT.Rows(e.Item.ItemIndex).Delete()
    Session("Cart") = objDT

    dg.DataSource = objDT
    dg.DataBind()
    lblTotal.Text = "$" & GetItemTotal()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Is the cart in session really not null?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and ran it through a couple of times and firgured it out.
On the inital page load Session("Cart") is nothing. Causing the Object Reference error when adding a new column to the DataTable.

Setting your DataTable equal to the Session("Cart") like this :

```
objDT = CType(Session("Cart"), DataTable)
```

will give it a value of nothing. Instead, do this on the inital page load :

```
objDT = New Data.DataTable
```

After Session("Cart") has been set you, can set the datatable equal to Session("Cart") like you did before.

The entire function :

```
Function makeCart()
    objDT = New Data.DataTable
    objDT.Columns.Add("StockID", GetType(Integer))
    objDT.Columns("StockID").AutoIncrement = True
    objDT.Columns("StockID").AutoIncrementSeed = 1

    objDT.Columns.Add("StockItemName", GetType(String))
    objDT.Columns.Add("StockItemValue", GetType(Decimal))
    Session("Cart") = objDT
End Function
```